# Oauth + Laravel + Vuejs + MongoDB 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: mongodb, laravel, oauth-2.0, vue.js, laravel-passport

everyone. I am currently developing a web app. I started to develop on a laptop. Then I mapped the code folder on the laptop to my pc. On my laptop, everything works correctly. But on the PC i cant get authenticated. I get 500 Internal server error. I am using `Oauth`, `Laravel`, `laravel passport`, `vuejs` and m`ongodb`. i am currently accessing the mongodb server remotely if it matters.
Here is the login method

```
methods: {
    login(){
      var data = {
        client_id:'58a08f3588053a6d947dc902',
        client_secret:'E1STUJipgmCO2h9gtkN2Vl1fTpgJCuiW2SrktshM',
        grant_type:'password',
        username:this.userid,
        password:this.password
      }
      this.$http.post("http://localhost:8000/oauth/token", data)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
      /*
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
      })*/
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What does the error say? Have you checked the log?

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank which log sir? and where to find it? is it the npm-debug.log? nothing mentioned there.

Comment: Laravel log, `storage/logs`

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank here is the log https://paste.laravel.io/e82EK

Comment: There is your error: `Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found`.